# Significance/symbolism of toe-licking scene

Tags: the-last-emperor

In *The Last Emperor*, on the day of Pu Yi's inauguration as Emperor of Manchukuo, his wife the Empress goes a bit nutty. First she eats some white flowers. Then later Eastern Jewel starts licking her toes.

I never got the significance of these scenes, especially the toe-licking one. Perhaps the flower-eating scene was just to show that she was becoming a slightly-crazed opium addict.

But what was the toe-licking one about?  Is there some hint of lesbianism or what was that about?

Comment: More than 'some hint', IMO.